# ridit transform ordinal variable in R

Tags: r, numeric, feature-extraction

Ridit scoring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridit_scoring) is often used to transform an ordinal categorial variable ino relative frequency (proportion of cases below a given value, plus one half of the proportion at that value).

How would you do this in `R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FURTHER UPDATE**
These and several other functions are now available in the CRAN package `ridittools`, maintained by yours truly.

**UPDATE**
Remove rather silly code involving constructing a conversion matrix, I'd forgotten about cumsum()

```
# Convert vector of counts to ridits

to.ridit <- function(v) {
  (cumsum(v) - .5 * v) / sum(v)
}

# Calculate mean ridit for vector of counts relative to reference group

mean.ridit <- function(v, ref) {
  sum(to.ridit(ref) * v ) / sum(v)
}

# Calculate mean ridits for several groups
# x is matrix of counts
# margin is 1 for groups in rows, 2 for groups in columns
# If ref is omitted, totals across groups are used as reference group
# If ref is a vector of counts, it's used as reference group
# Otherwise, ref is the number (or name if it exists) of the group to use as reference

ridits <- function(x, margin, ref=NULL) {
  if (length(ref) > 1) {
    refgroup <- ref
  } else if (length(ref) == 1) {
    if (margin==1) {
      refgroup <- x[ref,]
    } else {
      refgroup <- x[, ref]
    }
  } else {
    refgroup <- apply(x, 3-margin, sum)
  }
  apply(x, margin, mean.ridit, refgroup)
}
```

Example (Fleiss, 1981: severity of car accidents):

```
to.ridit(c(17, 54, 60, 19, 9, 6, 14))

[1] 0.04748603 0.24581006 0.56424581 0.78491620 0.86312849 0.90502793 0.96089385
```

**Note**
Although my code is somewhat less flexible than the Ridit::ridit package mentioned in another answer, it seems to be quite a bit faster:

```
# Influenza subtypes by age as of week ending 2/24/18 (US CDC)

> flu.age
        BY  BV  BU   H3   H1
0-4    274  91  92 1808  500
5-24  1504 274 698 5090  951
25-64 1665 101 567 7538 1493
65+   1476  35 330 9541  515

# Using CRAN package

> system.time(ridit(flu.age,2))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.746   0.007   3.756 

# Using my code

> system.time(ridits(flu.age,2))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.001   0.000   0.000
```

Comment: Hi there, I think the `to.ridit` function should have `+ .5 * v` instead of `- .5 * v`

Comment: Nope. cumsum(v)[n] is the sum of the elements up through *and including* n. We want only half of the last one, so we have to subtract.

Answer (score 1):

The following package may solve your problem. Especially the command `Ridit::ridit` is useful as it is described in the following way.

An extension of the Kruskal-Wallis test that allow specify arbitrary reference group. Also provide
Mean Ridit for each group. Mean Ridit of a group is an estimate of probability a random observation
from that group will be greater than or equal to a random observation from reference group.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ridit/Ridit.pdf

An alternative approach would be using a binary choice model like Probit, Logit or Exact Logit and extracting the predicted independent variables, i.e. 0 or 1.